# Creating firebase rules for indexing with nested tree structure

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to set the indexing for 'customerNumber' and 'rentalDate' fields on my firebase database as shown below. I'm using dynamic keys (UUID) for 'bookstore', 'bookId', 'customerId'.

What is the syntax for defining dynamic keys under the 'FIREBASE RULES'? I tried using '$xxxx' after looking at another stack overflow post but I'm not sure its the correct one.

The firebase documentation is good and it would be more helpful if they provided more examples for nested structures with dynamic keys.

```
   "BookStores":
   {
      "$bookStore1":
       {
          "BOOKS_RENTAL":
            {
              "$book1":
                 {
                   "RENTAL_INFO":
                    {
                      "rentalDate":"1121212.121212"
                    }
                 }
              "$book2":{}
              "$book3":{}
            }
            "CUSTOMERS":
            {
               "$customerId":
                 {
                    "CUSTOMER_INFO":
                        {
                          "customerNumber":"650-123-4567"
                        }
                 }
            }
       }
      "$bookStore2":
       {
       }
      "$bookStore3":
       {
       }
   }
```

And my rules is setup like this. I need to index on 'customerNumber' and 'rentalDate'

```
{
  "rules": 
   {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,

     "BookStores":
      {
        "$bookStoreId":
         {
           "BOOK_RENTAL":
             {
               "$bookId":
                 {
                   ".indexOn":"RENTAL_INFO/rentalDate"
                 }
             }
            "CUSTOMERS":
             {
               "$customerId":
                 {
                   ".indexOn":"CUSTOMER_INFO/customerNumber"
                 }
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

However I'm still getting the warning in Xcode. Anything obvious I'm missing or doing wrong ?

**Update:**

I'm querying against rentalDate in a date range:

```
FQuery* query = [[[ref queryOrderedByChild:@"RENTAL_INFO/rentalDate"] queryStartingAtValue:startDateQueryString] queryEndingAtValue:endDateQueryString];
```

The 'ref' points to

```
'firebase.io/Bookstores/$bookstore1/BOOK_RENTAL'
```

For initial data download I use 'observeSingleEventOfType':

```
[query observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot)
```

And for updates I'm using 'observeEventType':

```
[query observeEventType:eventType withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot)
```

where eventType is 'FEventTypeChildAdded', 'FEventTypeChildChanged', 'FEventTypeChildRemoved'

Comment: The Firebase documentation fairly explicitly warns against nesting lists like you're doing. That might be a factor in why it doesn't contain examples on how to define indexes for it.

Comment: Aside from that: what query are you running in your XCode? Show the minimal code that is necessary for us to understand where you are running a query, and what child you are ordering on.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ... any thoughts on this ? I've added more detail as you've asked.

Comment: There is no path `'firebase.io/Bookstores/$bookstore1/BOOK_RENTAL'`, in your JSON it's `'firebase.io/Bookstores/$bookstore1/BOOKS_RENTAL'` (plural).